# Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault on USRP E312 running a OFDM example from GNURADIO

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, usrp

Im trying to run an OFDM example on a USRP E312, i generated the python script on GNURADIO 3.8 and UHD 4.3 (PC and USRP), but i get a Segmentation fault error.

This is the terminal output from the E312:

```
root@ni-e31x-32132F0:~# python3 ofdm_loopback.py
[INFO] [UHD] linux; GNU C++ version 9.2.0; Boost_107100; UHD_4.3.0.0-0-g1f8fd345
[INFO] [MPMD] Initializing 1 device(s) in parallel with args: mgmt_addr=127.0.0.1,type=e3xx,product=e310_sg3,serial=32132F0,name=ni-e31x-32132F0,fpga=n/a,claimed=False
[INFO] [MPM.main] Launching USRP/MPM, version: 4.3.0.0-g1f8fd345
[INFO] [MPM.main] Spawning RPC process...
[WARNING] [MPM.PeriphManager] Skipping HW/SW compatibility check!
[INFO] [MPM.PeriphManager] Device serial number: 32132F0
[WARNING] [MPM.PeriphManager] Found more EEPROM paths than daughterboards. Ignoring some of them.
[INFO] [MPM.RPCServer] RPC server ready!
[INFO] [MPM.RPCServer] Spawning watchdog task...
[INFO] [MPM.PeriphManager] init() called with device args `fpga=n/a,mgmt_addr=127.0.0.1,name=ni-e31x-32132F0,product=e310_sg3'.
[INFO] [0/Radio#0] Performing CODEC loopback test on channel 0 ...
[INFO] [0/Radio#0] CODEC loopback test passed
[INFO] [0/Radio#0] Performing CODEC loopback test on channel 1 ...
[INFO] [0/Radio#0] CODEC loopback test passed
[WARNING] [MULTI_USRP] Calling multi_usrp::recv_async_msg() is deprecated and can lead to unexpected behaviour. Prefer calling tx_stream::recv_async_msg().
[INFO] [MULTI_USRP]     1) catch time transition at pps edge
[INFO] [MULTI_USRP]     2) set times next pps (synchronously)
Press Enter to quit: Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Thread 0xb6c09010 (most recent call first):
  File "ofdm_loopback.py", line 132 in main
  File "ofdm_loopback.py", line 140 in <module>
Segmentation fault
root@ni-e31x-32132F0:~#
```

this is the workflow that i implemented.

[workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBoiA.png)